# How to use Bind() in EditItemTemplate for nullable property?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a `GridView` bound to some Entity Datasource. Editing is enabled. Entity shown in GridView is associated with another entity. Let's say I'm displaying `Machines` which are creating `Products` (none or one product type per machine). I'm displaying name of the product in gridview with

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# ((Machine)Container.DataItem).Product == null ? "-" : ((Machine)Container.DataItem).Product.Name %>'>
    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

which works well. Now I want to be able to edit associated product in `EditItemTemplate`. So I added

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddProducts" DataSourceID="dsProducts" 
            DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ProductID" 
            SelectedValue='<%#  Bind("Product.ProductID") %>'
            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

It's not working because when machine doesn't have a product associated there is no matching `SelectedValue` and anyway `Product` is `null`. I added empty item to DropDownList which should be selected when machine has no product. And also if I edit machine with product and choose this item, column should be nulled.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work now. `GridView` automatically converts nulls to empty strings, so the problem was not with binding but with the special item I added for null values.

Changing

```
<asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
```

to

```
<asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
```

solved the problem instantly...

Comment: please mark it as answer if this solved your issue. you can mark your own as  answer.

Comment: I can't do this yet. 24h or 48h need to pass, I don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridView's events` such as `RowDataBound` or `RowEditing`. One of the approach is:

```
private void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
         int index = e.NewEditIndex;
         GridView1.EditIndex = index;
         DropdownList ddrList = Gridview1.Rows[index].FindControl("ddProducts") as DropDownList;
         DataRowView view = (DataRowView)GridView1.Rows[index].DataItem;
         if(!ddrList.FindItemByValue(view.Row["Product.ProductID"].ToString().Equals(String.Empty))
            ddrList.FindItemByValue(view.Row["Product.ProductID"].ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately looks like `ddrList` and `view` are both nulls. Are you sure it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Product.ProductID") != null ? Bind("Product.ProductID") : 0 %>'
```

Obviously, replace the 0 with whatever you want.

Comment: `Eval()` is only for displaying data as far as I know. The main concern here is to save value back to DB.

Comment: Just edited my answer. I changed the true case to use Bind instead of Eval - that should work now, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately: `The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, give this a shot:

```
SelectedValue='<%# CheckIfValueIsNull(Bind("Product.ProductID"), 0).ToString() %>'
```

Add a function in your code behind to handle DBNull:

```
protected object CheckIfValueIsNull(object value, object nullValue)
{
    return value != DBNull.Value ? value : nullValue;
}
```

Comment: Still same error, that's odd... But anyway I think binding it this way will try to change ID of Product instead of change column ProductID in Machine. Maybe I should try bind to ProductID column, but I don't have this property mapped...

Comment: Is it possible that you could modify your product object so that it returns -1 instead of null? That way, you could just add a ListItem to the dropdown with a value of "-1".

Comment: I'm wrong about changing ID. It binds it ok when I do `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Product.ProductID") %>'` but this ofcourse works only when there is a product associated with a machine.

Comment: Wow, just found out something. Silly me. It's working now. I'll explain in answer.